# Angular 7 : How to fix value overwriting during dynamic field addition?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am working on an Angular application, wherein I have to do some configuration setup using 4 fields:

- Department Name (drop down)
- Service Name (drop down)
- Status (text field)
- Level (text field).

I want to add multiple set of these fields and create a JSON structure.

- 'Department Name' and 'Service Name' values are fetched using API calls.
- 'Service Name' options is populated based on 'Department Name' selected.

Though I am able to add the fields dynamically, but when I select nth Department Name, corresponding Service Name overwrites all (n-1) 'Service Name' fields.

Here is my `component.html` file:

```html
//mapFormGroup returns FormArray for given set of fields
<div *ngFor="let map of mapFormGroup.controls; let i = index;">
    <div [formGroupName]="i" class="row">
        <label>Department Name</label>
        // getServices fetches all services for selected department
        <select class="form-control" formControlName="deptId" type="text" (change)="getServices($event.target.value)">
            // deptList contains list of all departments
            <option *ngFor="let dept of deptList" [value]="dept.id">{{dept.name}}</option>
        </select>
        <label>Service Name</label>
        <select class="form-control" formControlName="serviceName" type="text">
            // serviceList contains list of all services for given department
            <option *ngFor="let service of serviceList" [value]="service.wfName">{{service.description}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect correct mapping of Department & Service Name fields. But the latest one is overwriting previous entries.

Comment: What does your component look like?  It seems like `serviceList` is a variable shared by all rows in the form.  So if you change it for one form it will change for all forms.  It sounds like you need a dedicated `serviceList` per row.

Comment: Yes, something of that sort, but I cannot have different names for single field, so in turn dedicated serviceList per row won't be possible.Even if it is, I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by making below change:

### In my `component.html`:

```html
    //mapFormGroup returns FormArray for given set of fields
    <div *ngFor="let map of mapFormGroup.controls; let i = index;">
    <div [formGroupName]="i" class="row">
    <label>Department Name</label>
    // getServices fetches all services for selected department
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="deptId" type="text" (change)="getServices($event.target.value,**i** )">
    // deptList contains list of all departments
    <option *ngFor="let dept of deptList" [value]="dept.id">{{dept.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <label>Service Name</label>
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="serviceName" type="text">
    // serviceList contains list of all services for given department
    <option *ngFor="let service of **fnServiceList(i)**" [value]="service.wfName">{{service.description}}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

---

### In my `component.ts`:

```
// New function added to return array element of current index 
**fnServiceList(row){
    return this.serviceList[row];
}**

// Added row as input to assign the output to current index of array 
getServices = function (dept, **row**) {
    // Fetch the services for given department in "services" variable
    this.serviceList**[row]** = services;
    // Instead of: "this.serviceList = services;"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataSource: ServiceName[]; // create class for service or can have just [];
ngOnInit(){
 this.dataSource = [];
  this.ServiceNameService.getServiceDetails().subscribe( resp => {
    resp.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element);
      const config = new  ServiceName(
      element.ServiceId, element.Name); // this is constructor or if general array 
       //change accordingly 
      this.dataSource.push(config);
  });
}
getServices(val){
this.ServiceNameList = this.dataSource.filter(obj => 
             String(obj.DepartmentName).toUpperCase() === String(val));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jay. I am already doing this. Also, the lists contain proper values, but the field id is 'serviceName' across rows (as and when a row is added). Thus the overwriting is happening.